# Identify max dated records at a point in time

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to identify the latest records in a DB for days in the past. The DB has Columns:

```
Record ID, AccNum, PersonNum, Start Date, End Date
```

Let's say for `AccNum 123` and `PersonNum 246` they have records for start & end dates:

```
Record ID 1 Start Date 18-Jun-16 End Date 19-Jun-16
Record ID 2 Start Date 19-Jun-16 End Date 23-Jun-16
Record ID 3 Start Date 24-Jun-16 End Date 26-Jun-16
```

I want the query to tell me the max dated record for a particular day. Eg on the 20th of Jun it would be `Record ID 2`, on the 25th of Jun it would be `Record ID 3`, for the `AccNum` and `Person Num` combination `123-246`.

Comment: thanks for edit - am new user

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  But I think you can use `select ... from <your table> where <your date> between start and end`.